# AngularJS modal window scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have problem with scopes of controllers. I'm using controller as directive and I have code similar to this example:

```
<div ng-controller="ItemsController as itemCtrl">
   <table> .. some data ... </table>
   <a ng-click="itemCtrl.createItem()">Create new item</a>
</div>

<div id="create-form" ng-controller="ItemFormController as itemFormCtrl">
  <form ng-submit="itemFornCtrl.saveItem()">... form inputs ...</form>
</div>

<div id="edit-items" ng-controller="MultipleItemsEdit as multiEditCtrl">
   ... table with some data .... 
   <!-- I need this -->
   <a ng-click="itemCtrl.createItem()">Create new item</a>
   <!-- -->
</div>
```

Basically there are 3 isolated scopes. But I need to break this isolation and call methods from one scope on another.

I'm currently using ugly "delegate" kind of hack.

Controllers and their methods are not so interesting, only interesting methods are ItemsController.createItem():

```
this.createItem = function(dataCollection) { 
    angular.element( $("#create-form) ).controller().createNewItem(dataCollection);
}
```

and ItemFormController.createNewItem(dataCollection):

```
this.createNewItem = function(dataCollection) {
   ... some initialization .... 
   $("#add-item").dialog( "open" );
}
```

I need to call createNewItem method on ItemFormController to show modal box. But I cannot do it directly, so I'm using method createItem which gets the create-form element and its controller and calls createNewItem method on it. It is kind of a delegate. But I don't like it, because I need to call createNewItem from many places of my code and I don't want to populate all my controllers with this kind of delegate methods.

Maybe I could make these delegates on some kind of root controller, but isn't there any better solution?

Comment: Can I see more of the directive code please?

Comment: Shared controller code typically goes in a service/factory.

Comment: I know, but in HTML you bind angular actions typically to controllers, right? Or you can also bind it to service?

Answer (score 0):

You can nest the edit controller scope in the list controller scope by simply nesting the divs (move the div with `ng-controller="MultipleItemsEdit as multiEditCtrl"` into the div with `ng-controller="ItemsController as itemCtrl"`). That way the you can call the method directly.